# How to get Talend to wait for a file to land in S3

Tags: talend

I have a file that lands in AWS S3 several times a day.  I am using Talend as my ETL tool to populate a warehouse in Snowflake and need it to watch for the file to trigger my job.  I've tried tWaitForFile but can't seem to get it to connect to S3.  Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check below link automate pipeline using S3 and lambda to trigger files  to talend job.
[Automate S3 File Push](https://community.talend.com/s/article/Automate-S-file-processing-with-Talend-Cloud-and-AWS-Lambda-0wNKj?language=en_US)